# how to submit form as JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, serialization

what I am doing is creating a form using JSON this form can then be edited a and produce new JSON object. The problem I am having seems to be with getting the form id.
The code I am using to return a JSON object is:

```
form = document.forms[0];
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    alert("start serializeObject");
    var o = {};
    var a = this.seralizeArray();
    $.each(a, function(){
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
    alert(o);
};

$(function() {
    alert("here");
    form.submit(function(){
        result.append(JSON.stringify(form.serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

This just refresh's the pageI am not sure why.
This program is not on a server and not be used on a server.
by this I mean It is only every going to be run locally on a local machine, with no apache2 setup.

Thanks.

Comment: You have quite a lot of typos in your code. `from`, `seralize`

Comment: This program is not on a server and not be used on a server. means? Please write clearly the requirement..if u want to submit data as json then check jquery ajax {post:'json'} example..

Comment: The page is just refreshing, probably, because your html code has a submit button, and a form with the action and method. This way html is trying to submit. Next time post your html also

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You code can be written pretty easy. This is how I do it:

Ajax:

```
$('#formID').on('submit',function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data : $('#formID').serialize(),
        success: function(json) {
            alert('all done');
        }
    });
});
```

If you are not sending it with Ajax, why would you do this? If you are simply submitting the form, you can do it using PHP like this:

```
<?php
$json_object = json_decode($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Apologies I am sending it with ajax.

Comment: Try my first code then. I think it will make things a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#formID').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'submit.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data : $('#formID').serialize(),
        success: function(json) {
        alert('all done');
    }
    });
});
```

if you want not redirect or refresh use e.preventDefault();